# Como usar o GIT para listar os arquivos alterados no branch

Tags: git

Como exibir a lista de todos os arquivos alterados em um *branch* sem precisar informar o **`commit X`** até **`commit Y`**.

Estava usando o seguinte comando abaixo para listar os *commit's* e conseguir pegar o *Hash* dos commit's:

```
    git log origin/master..HEAD
```

#### O retorno é algo parecido com

```
commit 234567893fcc38567c634e810aa904c7497d7fdc (HEAD -> feature/task/123, origin/feature/task/123)
Author: Nome <meu@em.ail>
Date:   Wed Aug 19 12:37:46 2020 -0300

    Alterada a função x

commit 022e45f07f259b4e8f49679e6a0531c404179cb9
Author: Nome <meu@em.ail>
Date:   Wed Aug 19 12:35:47 2020 -0300

    Alterada a variável y

commit 75094ffa564f1b4a3d19ffaebf2afc358585fc81
Author: Nome <meu@em.ail>
Date:   Wed Aug 19 12:25:58 2020 -0300

    Adicionado regra

commit 12345678298af92e713b90b9335bcb813eda85fd
Author: Nome <meu@em.ail>
Date:   Wed Aug 19 12:21:47 2020 -0300

    Correção de bug
```

E o comando abaixo para listar os arquivos do **`commit A`** até o **`commit C`** pegando os primeiros 8 carácteres do hash do commit.

```
   git show --pretty="format:" --name-only  12345678..23456789 | sort | unique
```

#### O retorno é a lista abaixo:

```
    arquivo1.js
    arquivo2.css
    arquivo3.html
```

Minha dúvida é como faço para retornar de uma forma mais simples todos os arquivos alterados no **branch** sem precisar informar o *Hash* do *commit* inicial e final?

Também dei uma olhada na documentação: [Commit Hystory](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Para listar os arquivos sem precisar informar o **`hash`** use:

```
  git log feature/FI/85683 --not master --name-status --pretty=format:"%x09"
```

#### Para exibir a lista sem repetir o nome dos arquivos use  `| sort | unique`  :

```
  git log feature/FI/85683 --not master --name-status --pretty=format:"%x09" | sort | unique
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode-se utilizar o comando `git diff` com a opção `--name-only` para listar apenas o nome dos arquivos. Veja a [documentação](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).

Este comando pode ser utilizado com um ou dois parâmetros. Com um vai comparar o commit apontado com o estado atual de seu diretório. Outra opção é passar dois parâmetros e ele vai comparar os dois diretamente.

Por exemplo, suponha que você esteja na branch que está desenvolvendo, pode-se usar:

```
git diff --name-only master
```

Tenha em mente que caso após a criação da branch tenham sido feitos commits na Master, esses também vão ser listados como uma diferença. Se isso não for um problema (e.g. você souber que não houveram commits na master desde então) esse comando mais simples é suficiente.

Para obter apenas os do branch estritamente falando você pode utilizar o comando mais completo e usar como referência para o diff o primeiro commit do branch:

```
git diff --name-only <BranchDevelop> <CommitOriginalDaBranch>
```

Para obter o primeiro commit da branch você pode utilizar o commando [merge-base](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base) que acha o melhor ancestral comum entre dois commits:

```
git merge-base BranchDevelop Master
> 5e3299f35dc05c8ab69cb0e62c3fbecb161afb87
git diff --name-only BranchDevelop 5e3299f35dc05c8ab69cb0e62c3fbecb161afb87
```

Ou, se preferir pode utilizar das funções de seu shell para pegar diretamente o retorno do primeiro parâmetro:

```
git diff --name-only BranchDevelop $(git merge-base BranchDevelop Master)
```

Obs: Acredito que essa sintaxe de `$()` possa não ser aceita por todos os bash/shell, e neste caso deve ser utilizado o equivalente com [back-tick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27432) `` `git merge-base BranchDevelop Master` ``